# Compile issues: LIBUSB_1 with cmake project on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

**First Attempt**

In my cmake/c++ project I get the following error when compiling:

```
C:\local\projects\synergy-usb\synergy-through-usb-master>cmake .
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/arch
   used as include directory in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/net
LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY
    linked by target "arch" in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/arch

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

So I am missing libusb libraries.

**Second Attempt**

So now I have found a version of libusb_1 (libusbx-1.0.18-win) which includes the folders:

- examples
- include
- MinGW32
- MinGW64
- MS32
- MS64

I copied MS64/dll (windows 64-bit) contents and put it here:

```
C:\local\libs\libusbx
```

I added this path to my PATH variable and then tried to run cmake again:

C:>cd local\projects\synergy-usb\synergy-through-usb-master

```
C:\local\projects\synergy-usb\synergy-through-usb-master>cmake .
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY
    linked by target "arch" in directory C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/src/lib/arch

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Now I am stuck again. I have no idea what it wants me to do. It knows where libusb is...

**Edit**

Here is the contects (part of) the CMakeLists.txt that has libusb in it:

```
find_package(libusb-1.0 REQUIRED)

set(inc
    .
    ../base
    ../common
    ../mt
    ../platform
    ../synergy
    ${LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

if (UNIX)
    list(APPEND inc
        ../../..
        ../arch
    )
endif()

include_directories(${inc})
add_library(arch STATIC ${src})

set(libs
    ../lib
    ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARIES}
    )

if (WIN32)
    if (GAME_DEVICE_SUPPORT)
        list(APPEND libs synxinhk)
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(arch ${libs})
```

**Edit 2**

I added the following lines into the findlibusb-1.0.cmake file:

```
set(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY C:\\local\\libs\\libusbx\\libusb-1.0.dll)
message(STATUS "***********************************>   LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY: ${LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY}")
```

Here is the output from that:

```
C:\local\projects\synergy-usb\synergy-through-usb-master>cmake .
-- ***********************************>   LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY: C:\local\libs\libusbx\libusb-1.0.dll
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: C:/local/libs/libusbx
--  - Libraries: C:\local\libs\libusbx\libusb-1.0.dll
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master
```

Still does not build, but this particular library seems to be added ok now :)

Comment: Please, provide precise command, which fills variable `LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY`. Probably, it is `find_library(LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY ...)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, I am very new to cmake, where would I add this? Also this is a project from git (https://github.com/iHateInventNames/synergy-through-usb) so it does not feel right that I would need to modify the cmake files?

Comment: @Tsyvarev - unless you meant for me to post that bit of cmake code? - I have added it to my question :p

Comment: The variable is filled in [cmake_modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake](https://github.com/iHateInventNames/synergy-through-usb/blob/master/cmake_modules/Findlibusb-1.0.cmake#L62). This `find_library()` call checks followed names of the library: `usb-1.0` and `usb`, possibly prefixed by `lib` and having appropriate extension (`.dll`). Which file under your directory `C:\local\libs\libusbx` has such name (so, it could be found by `find_library`)? BTW, this `Find*` script has *bad* implementation (it should report error), name (`-1.0`) and usage.

Comment: @Tsyvarev ahh, ok. So it looks like it can find the dll but probably (in my case) not find the actual .h file. I have put the .h file in `C:\local\libs\libusbx` but in findlilbusb1-.0.cmake `find_path(LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR..)` seems to be looking in linux-like paths (e.g. /usr/include). How do I point it to my .h file? do I need to move it elsewhere?

Comment: The second buil log in you question post doesn't contain errors about `LIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR`, do it? If so, this variable is set somehow and `find_path()` call is *not your problem now*. But `LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY` variable is not set, so you need  to concetrate on `find_library()` call, which is intended to set it. As `C:\local\libs\libusbx` is included into PATH, `find_library()` will search in it (precise search algorithm is described in [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html)). So, which **existed** file you *expect* to be found by that command?

Comment: @Tsyvarev no, you are right I got it the wrong way around. So in C:\local\libs\libusbx I have copied in: `libusb.h, libusb-1.0.dll, libusb-1.0.lib, libusb-1.0.pdb`.... so I was really expecting it to be able to find all of these files... this is what really confuses me :(

Comment: Probably, `lib` prefix is not common for Windows, so `find_library()` doesn't check it. You may try to set [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES.html) variable to `lib`: `cmake -D CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_PREFIXES=lib <other parameters>`. As last resort you may try to set `LIBUSB_1_LIBRARY` variable manually to `C:\\local\\libs\\libusbx\\libusb-1.0.dll` (doubling "\\" is needed for CMake processing). Either in the CMake cache (if you run cmake from GUI) or with `-D` option too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I used the brute force method that you suggested (manually set the variable). See "edit2" in my post for the output. I get further errors, but these are not part of this question. If you put your comment into an answer I will mark it up for you, thanks : )

Answer (score 1):

synergy had such approach to keep some 3rd party libs compressed in zip in ext subdirectory. synergy-through-usb though kept cmake way to specify include through `-DLIBUSB_1_INCLUDE_DIR=... -DLIBUSB_1_LIBRARY=...` for Windows.

So you just need go to 'ext' directory and uncompress its zip archives with libraries gtest, gmock and crypto.