# cmake: You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files

Tags: c++, windows, git, cmake

Windows 64bit using cmake to compile c++ project: `github.com/iHateInventNames/synergy-through-usb`

I fixed a previous issue in this post: [Compile issues: LIBUSB_1 with cmake project on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475866/compile-issues-libusb-1-with-cmake-project-on-windows)

So when I hit cmake now I get the following error:

```
> cmake .
-- Found libusb-1.0:
--  - Includes: C:/local/libs/libusbx
--  - Libraries: C:/local/libs/libusbx/libusb-1.0.lib
You have called ADD_LIBRARY for library cryptopp without any source files. This typically indicates a problem with your CMakeLists.txt file

-- Configuring done
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
CMake Error: CMake can not determine linker language for target: cryptopp
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/local/projects/synergy-usb/synergy-through-usb-master
```

What does this mean? how can I solve it / move on?

**Links to the install instructions**

both goto 404 errors...

- http://synergy-project.org/projects/synergy/wiki/Readme/?hl=pm
- http://synergy-project.org/projects/synergy/wiki/Compiling/?hl=pm

Comment: Did you follow installation instructions (if any)? Based on a quick browse through the project's CMakeLists, it would seem you're supposed to unpack `tools/cryptopp562.zip` into a directory called `tools/cryptopp562` before running CMake.

Comment: @Angew I would literally kill for installation instructions! - I have added the links to the instructions pages but they both error 404 :(   Thanks for the insight though, I did not spot there was a zio file to extract... i'll give that a go - if works I'll let you know and you can stick it as the answer :)

Comment: @Angew, This worked : ), it was a very simple issue in the end, thanks. If you add your comment as an answer I will mark it up.

Comment: I think synergy company deleting build instructions is in violation of GPL.  Anyone interested in forking a version that compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a quick browse through the project's CMakeLists, it would seem you're supposed to unpack `tools/cryptopp562.zip` into a directory called `tools/cryptopp562` before running CMake. This should definitely have been mentioned in the projects' installation instructions, if any.

More precisely, the file `tools/CMakeLists.txt` contains this code:

```
set(cpp_dir cryptopp562)

file(GLOB cpp_src ${cpp_dir}/*.cpp)

# ...

add_library(cryptopp STATIC ${cpp_src})
```

This means that the variable `cpp_src` is filled with source files taken from directory `cryptopp562` (relative to the CMakeList's directory, i.e. `tools`), and is then used to define the source files of library `cryptopp`. However, the project's distribution only contains `tools/cryptopp562.zip`. Unpacking that into directory `tools/cryptopp562` should provide the missing files.